# Change URL Get parameters

Tags: jquery, url, header, onchange

current window location : www.hello.com/home.php?optionone=1&optiontwo=2&optionthree=3

How can i change the get parameters and redirect it to the new URL depending on the onchange value of a select option ?

```
<select id=“optionone" onchange=“">

<option value=“1”>Option1</option>

<option value=“2”>Option2</option>

<option value=“3”>Option3</option>

<option value=“4”>Option4</option>

</select>
```

say, Option2 was selected from the above select list, it should then change the get parameter of option one to 2 (optionone=2) and redirect to
     www.hello.com/home.php?optionone=2&optiontwo=2&optionthree=3

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#optionone').change(function(){
var opt1 = $('#optionone').val();
window.location = 'http://hello.com/home.php?optionone'+opt1;
}
```

To get the URL param, use PHP `$_GET['optionone']`

Comment: Thanks, But the other get paratameteres need to exist though. ( &optiontwo=2&optionthree=3)

Comment: how can i get those two get values from the header ?

Comment: You're after me writing the whole thing out for you? This is the answer. Add and amend the var = opt1 to whatever you need. I've amended the answer for extracting the URL parameters.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Daniel's answer:

```
$("#optionone").change(function(){
  window.location = "http://www.hello.com/home.php?optionone="
                       + $(this).val()
                       + "&optiontwo=" + $("#optiontwo").val()
                       + "&optionthree=" + $("#optionthree").val();

});
```

You can access these within your `home.php` script via

```
$_GET["optionone"];
$_GET["optiontwo"];
$_GET["optionthree"];
```

However, rather than reloading the web page, why not use an Ajax call to get the data required and apply it to the various elements via jQuery?  This allows dynamic data updates without requiring a page reload or refresh.